# most convenient way to handle multiple data input menus in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working on an ios app which requires input data from the user. It is gathered through multiple views (view1: textboxes, view2: switches, view3: personal data)

I would like to gather all this data and make it accessible through all coming views. Is it possible to use 1 viewcontroller for  the three views or is there a more convenient method to push all data through the views?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didn't see the Swift tag, my bad, I'll see if I can translate to Swift to help you out since this is going to look very foreign to you.

viewController1 => stores some data

viewController2 => called by custom init like so

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)dataFromViewController1 
           textBody1:(NSString*)textBodydataFromViewController1 
              title1:(NSString*)titledataFromViewController1
```

swift, this is close to right

```
init(dataFromViewController1 : String, textBody1 : String, title1 : String) {
}
```

viewController3 => called by custom init like so

```
- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)dataFromViewController1 
           textBody1:(NSString*)textBodydataFromViewController1 
              title1:(NSString*)titledataFromViewController1  
           textBody2:(NSString*)textBodydataFromViewController2 
              title2:(NSString*)titledataFromViewController2
```

swift, close to right:

```
init(dataFromViewController1 : String, textBody1 : String, title1 : String, textBody2 : String, title2 : String) {
}
```

etc, etc, etc,

In your viewcontroller .m impelmentaiton file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)dataFromViewController1 
           textBody1:(NSString*)textBodydataFromViewController1 
              title1:(NSString*)titledataFromViewController1
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
     }
    return self;
}
```

This is an advanced forwarding method, very sleek, very easy, doesn't require delegation. I try to avoid delegation at all cost. When you have an app that exceeds a 40K lines of code then you'll wish you would have never used custom delegation methods and instead opted in to use custom forward transferring init methods.

using the swift stuff:

```
init(dataFromViewController1 : String, textBody1 : String, title1 : String, textBody2 : String, title2 : String) {
           self.dataFromViewController1 = dataFromViewController1
           self.textBody1 = textBody1
           self.title1 = title1
           self.textBody2 = textBody2
           self.title2 = title2
}
```

setting the Swift stuff:

```
var aPrettyCat = aPrettyCat(dataFromViewController1 : "cat", textBody1 : "cheese", title1 : "donuts", textBody2 : "pickles", title2 : "brownies")
```

Comment: Most of the new users asking questions tagged "swift" can't translate Obj-C code. If you're going to post answers, then at least translate them before posting.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as others mentioned I am not familiar with objective-C, only with swift.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, I did Swift it and you can see that, but even this swift stuff is going to be very very difficult ti grasp early on. I'll  add more in a minute, I can give you an example, but it's going to take a second